# How to AutoComplete my Functions in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, sublimetext3

In a code like:

```
def Add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

I write:

```
Add(
```

And I want to see something like:

> ...you have to give "a" value and "b" value

For example:
[Example in IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV1Tm.png)

I have installed Packages like [All Autocomplete](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/All%20Autocomplete) but it does not work like I wanted to.

I am just starting in Coding so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you describe is not in Sublime Text by default, and it is more common of a full featured IDE. But you should look into plugins that bring IDE features to ST3. For example, [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/#carousel-features) brings features similar to what you are desiring. Also, don't confuse Anaconda the Sublime Text plugin with [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python) the Python distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded Jedi -Autocomplete and it works fine!